# Can't do anything after moved launcher to bottom

Tags: unity

I used this http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/how-to-move-unity-launcher-to-bottom-of.html and when I restarted computer, launcher, panel and skype window showed for 1-2 seconds (launcher was on bottom) and disappeared.

I tried restart the computer, but this did not help. I set autologin, so I can't switch to Unity 2D. I tried ctrl+alt+backpace to log out, but nothing happened.

I don't want to reinstall system, because there are important files in home folder, and if I don't format `/home` partition all my settings will stay and I still have this problem.

How to fix it?

Comment: Did you set the reveal mode in CCSM to bottom? If not and the launcher is set to autohide, you need to move your mouse to the left to reveal it. If that's not it, you can try to press CTRL + ALT + T to launch a terminal and then run "ccsm" and see if the Unity plugin is enabled. Or, to remove this tweak, run: "rm ~/.compiz-1/plugins/libunityshell.so"

Comment: @AlinAndrei - as an aside - I've been looking at those russian forums, no updates as to when the fabled launchpad PPA will appear.  From your contacts, have you got any further info?

Comment: @fossfreedom no info so far unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

The solution is mentioned right on that page:

`rm ~/.compiz-1/plugins/libunityshell.so`

To run this, log in to safe mode (from GRUB), and remove the file from your `~/.compiz-1` folder.

Since you will be logging in as root when using safe mode, you will have to navigate to `/home/yourusername/.compiz-1/plugins/` manually and delete the file from there.

After this, restart and when you log in things will be back to normal.

---

P.S. don't use autologin!

Answer (score 0):

hit `alt+F2`. this will take you to a tty session. login to the session and run `unity --reset`  that will reset your unity settings. If needed you can run `sudo reboot` after unity restarts to reboot the computer.